# Unity IAP with new google IAP version 3 Null reference

Tags: unity-game-engine

We're running Unity 2018.4.35f1 (LTS) and Unity IAP 2.2.2 (verified for version), Since google announced the new billing version to be released in August 2nd 2021, we wanted to implement it, and after adding their unity purchasing package that can be found in their manual, they have a process which solves conflicts with the UIAP.
That process basically deletes the file: GoogleAIDL.aar.
Once this file is deleted I keep getting null references from Unity's editor processes, to be more specific:
[image]
and right after it,
[image]
Since these are Unity editor files in some assembly, I can't even tell what the issue is, but I can easily say that if I restore the GoogleAIDL.aar file, the null reference exception and the error prior to it are gone, with that said, google's manual states that if I have this aar file, the in-app purchasing won't work due to build conflict between UIAP and google's new billing system. (they even have a "fix" button that deletes it in their UI menu).

Can anyone shed some light on the matter as a google search really didn't yield any results...
(Adding that I did check the BillingMode.json file and seems to be fine, and in the correct project folder).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some running around the internet, I've found that there's absolutely no reason what so ever to use google's wrapper for Unity as Unity IAP has implemented all that is required starting version 2.2.2 (as far as I know), so for me updating to LTS 2018 and updating the Unity IAP while removing any trace of google's wrapper fixed everything.